# Floated divs are expanding the height of a container but the height is not being defined if I apply a percentage height to an inside div element

Tags: css, html

I have a container div it contains multiple floated divs I want a specific border div inside the container to have 90% height of the container itself however it doesn't seem to detect the height of the container even though I've applied clear:both at the end of the container and also overflow:hidden to to the container div.

Comment: Have you tried to use `jQuery` to dynamical detect the `height` of the div?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jquery atleast not that much. I just want the seperator2 div to have a height in percentage so I can make it responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `js` script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setHeight();
        $(window).resize(function() {
           $('.seperator2').css({ height: '50px'});
           setTimeout(function(){
              setHeight();
            },300);        
        });
   });
  function setHeight(){
     var contentH = $('.content').height();
     separatorH = parseFloat(contentH * 0.9);
     $('.seperator2').css({ height: separatorH });
  }
</script>
```

This script can be either in the head or at the very bottom of the page. Despite of the place, make sure first you link `jQuery` library.

**NOTE:** To link`jQuery` library in the head(or elsewhere in the page), use the script bellow:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:** you can set the `height` of the element to 0 or remove it completely. Still I would probably leave it as `height: 100;`; this will force the page to look decent, before the script is executed.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response and it seems to be detecting a height, however not properly, when I resize my browser the height does not change, evem though the height of the content div varies, the seperator divs height remains the same.

Comment: I have changed the `javascript`, check it now. This should maintain the `height`, when the window is resized.

Comment: It works now but there still is a problem, when I contract the page the height increases perfectly but when I expand the page the height remains the same max height it had obtained when It was contracted, any solution for this ?

Comment: So any clue on what I should do ?

Comment: Check the answer again. I have placed `$('.seperator2').css({ height: '50px'});` just after the `$(window).resize` function. See if it fix the bug this time.

Comment: Yes it is being reduced however some of the floated divs are escaping.

Comment: See above how the second `setHeight();` function is wrapped  with a timeout function -> `setTimeout(function(){ setHeight(); },300);`; Try this trick and see if it works.

Comment: ok Its working now thanks to you a bit of css modification its working.